# AutoLayout: Shifting from Portrait to Landscape doesn't update the UIScrollView Width

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout, landscape-portrait

In my application I'm using ScrollView to show full size images horizontally and its running perfect in `Portrait` mode but when I shift it to `Landscape` mode then the width of scrollview doesn't update.

Lets say I've 4 images and width of each image is 568 in Landscape mode so the total width of `UIScrollView` should be `2272` and actually it is. but it only show content of width `1136` i.e. 2.5 out of 4. And If I go to previous view and reload this view in Landscape then scrollview shows all the contents within its width (2272).

[image: output screen]

Here is my `Views hierarchy`:

[image: Views hierarchy]

I'm adding constraints as follow:

```
[mainScrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|[imgView(%f)]|", self.view.frame.size.height]
                                                                       options:kNilOptions
                                                                       metrics:nil
                                                                         views:views]];
    
[mainScrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|[imgView(%d)]|", width_size]
                                                                       options:kNilOptions
                                                                       metrics:nil
                                                                         views:views]];

[mainScrollView updateConstraints];
```

where `width_size = 2272`

You can find my `Code` there :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1noH4KPfAePTVVNb3lhZXlmZzA/edit?usp=sharing

I'm new to AutoLayout and stuck and don't know why this is happening, any help will be greatly appreciated.